# Navigation bar overflow when implementing adMob inside Recycleview

Tags: android, admob

I have ad every 10 cards.
when I am scrolling nearby the ad - its rendering the content above the system navigation bar.

Image for example:
[Android screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WQAP.png)

I have ItemView with adView (default is visibility="gone")
The listAdapter is:

```
        //show ad at X item
    if((position+1)%5 == 0){
        holder.adCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                //.addTestDevice("E7AC2F56BC1BF35EEC5C63E981C438A8")
                .build();
        holder.adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
    else {
        holder.adCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: And device/Android version.

Comment: I edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem with Native Ads

[Native ads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native)

Good sample at Github:
[sample](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admobhttps://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob)